# Can AWS Lambda reach/interact with S/FTP?

Tags: node.js, ftp, sftp, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I wrote some basic js to just list the files of a FTP but I get:

"Process exited before completing request"

Is that because Lambda can't interact with FTP?

I'm using jsftp btw.

Here's my setup:

- I use [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) to create the project
- For my lambda, I used nodejs and I'm using JSFTP to deal with the ftp stuff.

My code:

```
// Require Serverless ENV vars
var ServerlessHelpers = require('serverless-helpers-js').loadEnv();

// Require Logic
var lib = require('../lib');

// Lambda Handler
module.exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    lib.respond(event, function (error, response) {
        return context.done(error, response);
    });
};
```

My ftp lambda code:

```
var JSFtp = require("jsftp");

module.exports.respond = function (event, cb) {

    var ftp = new JSFtp({
        host: "host",
        user: "user",
        password: "password"
    });

    ftp.auth(ftp.user, ftp.password, function(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(res);

        ftp.ls(".", function (err, res) {
            var results = [];
            res.forEach(function (file) {
                results.push(file.name);
            });

            ftp.raw.quit();

            return cb(null, results.length);
        })
    });
};
```

I added some console.log() all over the place and it seems like it choked once it tried to ftp.auth.

The output I see in cloud watch:

```
START RequestId: __ID__ Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: __ID__
REPORT RequestId: __ID__    Duration: 526.46 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 33 MB  
Process exited before completing request
```

So it looks like it just choked somewhere...

Comment: The default timeout for a lambda function execution is 3 seconds. Your call might be taking longer and get terminated. You can try changing it to a larger value

Comment: Either your process is crashing (look for errors in the log) or you aren't calling context.succeed() at the end.

Comment: @mbaird updated op with the code im using

Comment: Did you create this with a Lambda template? The code looks wrong. Lambda should be passing you an event object and a context object. Your function is taking an event object and a callback function. I'm not sure your function is even being invoked by Lambda.

Comment: the code is generate using Serverless if u look at the first snippet, it has the event/context; those r passed to another method to deal with the logic..

Comment: It will probably help to log errors AND exit out of the function when they happen. You need to do this inside ftp.auth and ftp.ls. `if(err) { console.log('ERROR', err); return cb('Unable to get list');}`. If you don't do that the code will continue to run even though you aren't logged in or have some other config error. I was able to duplicate your issue by using the wrong credentials so I suspect you may have a problem there or with the host.

Comment: also, dumb question, but did you add `jsftp` to the module package.json and redeploy your function?

Comment: most definitely. from what ive seen if u dont add the module and do the require, lambda will exit with "unable to find package" type of error. right now im literally just seeing "process exit before finish"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in short, ftp will not work with lambda since they use ephemeral ports.

sftp will work nicely with lambda. i tested using java code via jsch with no issues; tho i cant see how it wouldnt work with any js sftp lib.

Comment: This is not true. Maybe it was when you answered this, so I won't downvote on that presumption. We have FTP transfer code in python working in production AWS Lambda.

Comment: not sure if anything has changed since i worked on it. note that this was before vpc was supported. i tried using java and js, didnt check python though.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/ says that incoming TCP connections are not allowed. This means FTP PASV won't work at least.    Q: What restrictions apply to AWS Lambda function code?

... Inbound network connections are blocked by AWS Lambda, and for outbound connections only TCP/IP sockets are supported, and ptrace (debugging) system calls are restricted. TCP port 25 traffic is also restricted as an anti-spam measure.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible tested just now.
Make sure ur timeout is set to be long enough and you are calling context.succeed() on process termination

```js
function __main__(event, context) {
    var JSFtp = require("jsftp");
    var ftp = new JSFtp({
        host: "speedtest.tele2.net",
        port: 21, // defaults to 21
    });
    ftp.ls(".", function(err, res) {
      var results = []; res.forEach(function(file) {
        results.push(file.name);
      });
      context.succeed(results);
    });
};
```

Comment: would the ftp need to auth first before attempting ls? or does creatnig the JSFtp already auth for u?

Comment: normally yes, but I just used a public ftp server for testing. Just ship your login credentials with the lambda function itself

Comment: yeah i did, literally hardcoded the creds. i will try a public ftp and see if that mkes a diff.

Comment: the code from your question is wrong. Note that the second parameters is `cb` in your method, is not a function, but an object with three primary functions `succeed, fail, done`. Need to be executed as in the example I provided

Comment: what do u mean by wrong? i ran the code using node and it ran just fine(minus the lambda stuff). i ran the code using Serverless and it ran fine. edit: the cb is correct, in the first snippet the 2nd param for response is a cb.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Lambda functions only have 3 seconds to complete.  If it takes longer than that, you'll get the error you are seeing.

You can adjust the timeout to anything up to 5 minutes. To change it using the `aws` CLI, run:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-lambda-function --timeout 300
```